# Why can nginx access /etc/passwd?

Tags: nginx, php, security, permissions

I'm trying to setup my new VPS with my couple sites.

nginx, php-fpm and other needed services installed.

I setup a nginx server block(virtual hosts) for my site, and then try to create a php file for test. Everything working well, but then I want to try `echo file_get_contents('/etc/passwd')` file for security check. And its work too, a test.php file can access my VPS etc/passwd file and more.

After I try `echo shell_exec('ls /')` and this show my root folders.

So is this normal? Or how can I prevent this. I want to deny access to all except `/var/www` for `www-data` user wich running php codes.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have sensitive information in any of those files, then you've done something wrong.

Comment: etc/passwd just for example, if can access here then access other files hosts too.

Comment: You don't want to deny the user access - you want to deny web clients access to them. You really **really** need to read basic information about securely configuring nginx.

Comment: I'm quiet unclear about your comment above me. Usually `passwd` file is readable for all users.If I were you, I will first check the permissions whether it been changed or not. Example of a default **/etc/passwd** file will be seen as `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1708 Mar  9 09:38 /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The passwd file is readable by all users.  This is perfectly normal.  Same for /.  Programs need access to /etc/passwd to map usernames to ids.  The actual passwords are stored in /etc/shadow which is more restricted.

If for some reason you don't want programs seeing those file you should look at creating a chroot jail which provides it with its own fake root directory and a seperate copy of all needed files.  But for most services this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent access outside of proscribed boundaries by setting up and using AppArmour or SELinux.

What you're really saying here is: "scripts that I put on the system and run have access to read world-readable files on the system."

Yes, yes they do.